# What services should I use for autobuild of computationally intensive dockers?

Tags: docker, devops, dockerhub

I have a [repo](https://github.com/hms-dbmi/Baysor) with a piece of software, and a docker for users who have installation problems. I need to re-build the docker every time I publish a new version, and also want to use automated testing after it. DockerHub has such functionality, but builds are too long and are killed by timeout. Also I can't use tests there, as some tests use ~8 Gb RAM.
Are there any other services for these tasks? I'm fine with paying for it, but don't want to spend time for long configuration and maintenance (e.g. for having my own build server).

Answer (score 0):

[TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/).
It's fairly easy to start, hosted CI service which is free as long as you're keeping the repo public.

It's well known, common and you will find thousands of helpful questions and answers under the [[travisci]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/travis-ci) tag

I'm adding a link to their documentation with example on how to build `Dockerfile`.
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/#building-a-docker-image-from-a-dockerfile

Also, I've tried to find memory and time limitations but couldn't find any in quick search.